# Erro no Visual Studio - Cannot find name 'Record'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, typescript, visual-studio-2015

Estou trabalhando em um projeto ASP.NET com c# no Visual Studio 2015 e me deparei com erro no arquivo `index.d.ts`. As mensagens de erro são `Cannot find name 'Record'` e `Cannot find name 'undefined'`.
Vi que seria algum erro relacionado ao TypeScript, mas não sei o que exatamente. Podem me dar um help? Já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atualiza o TypeScript para uma versão mais atualizada.

Nesse link tem o arquivo para o VS2015: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48593